# How can I type Horizontal line in console in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console, line

I want to type Horizontal line like '-' 'ㅡ' ..

'-' this is dash(is underbar with shift.. _ ). it is too short

'ㅡ' this is korean. it is fine but still short

Is there any other way??

I am drawing a coordinate system on the console.
I want horizontal and vertical lines of the same length

[image]

Comment: See: `–` (en dash), `—` (em dash), and `―` (horizontal bar). For more info check-out: [Dash ~ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). See also: [Box-drawing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't directly answer your question but maybe an [ASCII art npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-art) can help you? It supports drawing graphs with ASCII characters which can then be printed onto the console.